# Howto restore Trigger filesystem copy (*.TRG and *.TRN files) in addition to mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, trigger, mariadb, mysqldump

We use `mysqldump` for backup (without Trigger/Events/Routines included).

```
mysqldump --opt --flush-logs --single-transaction --ignore-table=mysql.event --all-databases
```

The triggers we copy with `cp` to backup folder. We use Galera 5.5.41-MariaDB-wsrep.

After restoring the `mysqldump`, howto restore the Triggers? Simple `cp` or are other tasks necessary?

```
# find . -name *.TRG
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/user_login.TRG
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/conversation.TRG
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/conversation_participant.TRG
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/accounttovacancyrelation.TRG
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcomment.TRG
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/user.TRG
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcommentlike.TRG

# find . -name *.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_conversation_participant_insert.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_conversation_update.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_accounttovacancyrelation_update.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_user_login_insert.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_accounttovacancyrelation_delete.TRN
./DB_SE_0_E7D2D18F_A20B_4FFF_89A7_5C10A103B505/trg_accounttovacancyrelation_insert.TRN
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/user_AFTER_DELETE.TRN
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcommentlike_AFTER_INSERT.TRN
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcommentlike_AFTER_DELETE.TRN
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/user_AFTER_INSERT.TRN
./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcomment_BEFORE_DELETE.TRN
```

example content of files

```
# cat ./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcomment_BEFORE_DELETE.TRN
TYPE=TRIGGERNAME
trigger_table=eventcomment

# cat ./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/user_AFTER_INSERT.TRN
TYPE=TRIGGERNAME
trigger_table=user

# cat ./DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED/eventcomment.TRG
TYPE=TRIGGERS
triggers='CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` TRIGGER `DB_SE_0_BEA81F9B_1391_4942_AC7D_F5CBD7CCBCED`.`eventcomment_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `eventcomment` FOR EACH ROW\nBEGIN\n    DELETE FROM eventcommentlike where eventcommentlike_comment = OLD.eventcomment_id;\nEND'
sql_modes=0
definers='test@%'
client_cs_names='utf8'
connection_cl_names='utf8_general_ci'
db_cl_names='latin1_swedish_ci'
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to copy `.TRN` and `.TRG` files.

Just make sure when you run mysqldump to sue the [`--triggers`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) option. It is already set by default. You also need the [TRIGGER privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger) in order to dump triggers.